# VBA looping issue. Only works on current tab

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am looking for a way with VBA in excel to loop through spreadsheet.  I found a lot of sites with recommendations on using a range function, but nothing specific enough that has solve the issues that I have. Macro will only work on current tab.  It will not loop through.

```
Sub UpdateAll()
'
' UpdateAll Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Call Update_OI

Next ws

End Sub



Sub Update_OI()
'
' Update_OI Macro

Dim rng As Range


For Colx = 3 To 81

    Cells(10, Colx).Select


  If ActiveCell.Offset(-8, 0) = "X" Then GoTo 4

  If ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0) = 0 Then GoTo 4

  If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then GoTo 4

  If ActiveCell.Value <> vbNullString Then GoTo 1


1
    goalvalue = Cells(70, Colx).Value
    Range(Cells(69, Colx), Cells(69, Colx)).GoalSeek Goal:=goalvalue, ChangingCell:=Range(Cells(10, Colx), Cells(10, Colx))


4
Next Colx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your update all as below. It should work now.

```
Sub UpdateAll()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Select
        Call Update_OI
    Next ws

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the sheet object to `Update_OI`, and try *not* to use Select/Activate - you can almost always avoid that, and doing so will make your code more robust.

```
Sub UpdateAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Update_OI ws
    Next ws
End Sub



Sub Update_OI(ws as Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range, Colx As Long

    For Colx = 3 To 81

        Set rng = ws.Cells(10, Colx)

        If rng.Offset(-8, 0).Value <> "X" And _
           rng.Offset(-3, 0).Value <> 0 And _
           Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then 


            goalvalue = ws.Cells(70, Colx).Value

            ws.Cells(69, Colx).GoalSeek Goal:=goalvalue, _
                   ChangingCell:=ws.Cells(10, Colx)
        End If

    Next Colx

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  I am getting a "Reference not valid." error for the following code: ws.Cells(69, Colx).GoalSeek Goal:=goalvalue, _
                   ChangingCell:=ws.Cells(10, Colx)

Answer (score 0):

**Below code works**

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = 11111
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**Try changing**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    
     Call Update_OI    
Next ws
```

**To**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    
     Call Update_OI    
Next ws
```

***Or was it just copy paste formating problem. In this case I will remove my answer as it si no answer :).***